# Keydown event not firing in user control obj

Tags: c#, wpf, keydown

I have a user control which is not declared in the designer.  I have a button that I want to have create this user control when I click it - it should initialize the user control and insert it in the main UI.

However, it happens that the user control has a key press event on it, which is not firing.

Why does this happen?

I already tried to attach the event on the user control itself but it seems that it's not firing at all.  Is there some kind of bug?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Code for initializing the control?

Comment: this it my code for creating new control

Comment: DetailsControl myControl = new DetailsControl(myAccount,new OptionalSettingsData(),Accounts);

Comment: I am not sure what details control is, but I don't see you subscribing to button click event.

Comment: its a user control the event is on the designer its on XAML

Comment: Can you post more UI code? that can help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Does the UserControl have keyboard focus when you press the key? Or does one of its child controls have keyboard focus?

Comment: <UserControl x:Class="Accounts.DetailsControl" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="Office2010Black" xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" d:DesignHeight="710" d:DesignWidth="1600" Focusable="True" KeyUp="Keyup">

Comment: @fmunkert before i press any key i tried to focus the user control but its not really firing

Comment: @fmunkert i tried to focus some of the part of the user control and press any key its working for some part of the user control dont see any problem attaching event on the user control itself

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to fix problems with code that you can't see, but in WPF, there are often reasons why `Bubbling` events like the `KeyDown` event don't fire. Occasionally certain controls may make use of these events and set them as handled internally, thereby stopping them from bubbling up any further.

The normal solution on these occasions is to use the related `Tunneling` events instead, which are raised *before* the `Bubbling` methods and *not* used internally by controls. So, while I can't guarantee that this will fix your problem, it is certainly worth trying to handle the [`UIElement.PreviewKeyUp` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewkeyup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the `UIElement.KeyUp` event.